# Can Azure Functions be Classes in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

Using .NET this is the default way of writing your Azure functions but can something similar be accomplished using Typescript / NodeJS?

I'm thinking of something along the lines:

```
// MyAzureFunction.ts

class MyAzureFunction implements SomeRunableInterface {
  async run(context, res) {}
}

module.exports = new MyAzureFunction()
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/develop-serverless-apps

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue, please follow the below steps

- Open azure portal, in search bar type **Function App** shown as below

[image]

- After Clicking on the **Function App** then click on **Create** as below

[image]

- After clicking on create, it will open a page where you need to fill the **Subscription**, **resource group**, **Function App Name**, **Runtime stack**, **version**, **region** and click on **review & create** as shown in below

[image]

- After creating function app in azure portal now its time to create a **HTTP trigger** using **typescript** in" visual studio code" (VS code)
- Open "VS code" and then Go to **azure icon** in VS code and Go to **Workspace** click on **+** and select **Create function** it will give a popup to create a new folder click on **yes**
  take the reference from below picture

[image]

- It will open a command palette, Select **Typescript** as shown and click **enter**

[image]

- select the **HTTP trigger**
  [image]
- After that select the HTTP trigger in the next field and click **enter** and in the next step select **anonymous**
- After creating **HTTP trigger** we need to deploy it into azure portal to a function app which have been created before the creation of HTTP trigger
- Now open "VS code" and click on deploy icon shown in below picture

[image]

- After clicking on **Deploy to function app** It will open a command palette Select **Subscription id** and select the function app to which you want to add HTTP trigger and click on **enter**. after successful deployment from the "VS code" in **output** you will find below picture

[image]

- Check the deployed HTTP trigger in Azure portal as shown below

[image]